# Android Spinner is not fully visible in custom ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, spinner

I need to show some data in a grid-like format. For that purpose, I am using a ListView and I have a separate XML layout defined for ListViewROW.

**Main.xml:**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/newback" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Tablerow> SOME OTHER CONTROLS HERE  </Tablerow>
        <Tablerow>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mylistview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">
            </ListView>
        </Tablerow>
    </TableLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

**ListViewRow.xml**

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/col1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:gravity="left"/>

            <TextView  android:id="@+id/col2"/>
            <TextView  android:id="@+id/col3"/>
            <TextView  android:id="@+id/col4"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/cmbOptions"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:prompt="@string/optionPrompt"/>
        android:text="" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagecorrectivedocument"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/crane_ins"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Problem**:

The problem is that in the resultant grid, the spinner control is not fully visible. Please see the screen shot:

[image: Screen shot].

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the XML for the spinner, try:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: GREAT THANKS, It worked for me. you know i have spent 4 hours on this issue???? THANKS again!!